# Bounfary Folding Hash Function

Tags: function, hash, boundary, folding

What is the value of the Boundary Folding Hash Function if K = 43-57-69 and TSize = 100?
[A]
43

[B]
69

[C]
57

[D]
87

If it is Shift Folding I know how to slolving. I sum 43 57 and 69. After that, I mod with Tsize is 100. (43 + 57 + 69)%100=69. But with Boundary I can't